# What is the most efficient way to install a large mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, installation

I'm creating an installation for a web CMS-like system. Obviously it has many tables and rows with some pre-defined data so that the user can get up and running within minutes.

Initially it was just using mysql commands in a php script to create a database and then create tables etc. but as the software has grown and become more complex, I wanted to see if there is a better/more efficient way to do this that isn't slow or heavy on the server load.

I've wondered about maybe importing the SQL structure via a .sql file in a php system command, like a mysqldump, but importing rather than exporting. I haven't tried this so I'm not sure if that's any better than just doing loads of mysql_query's.

I also realise `mysqli` is the new way to do things now, but our systems haven't been upgraded for that yet so it will only be considered an option if it really **IS** the most efficient way.

If anyone has any experience with creating PHP/MySQL software installers, or knows any pointers to help, that would be great :)

Comment: A very fast way is to use a sql file. Tools like phpMyAdmin can help you with the import of such files. Since they can be gzipped uploads are fast, too.

Comment: If the database is large phpmyadmin will probably not help you as it will timeout during the processing. However the mysql.exe processor works well and has no limitations on size or runtime. The other benefit is you can run it from the command line or from a batch file as part of the install. `mysql -uUsername -pPassword DatabaseName < "\PathToSQLFile\hugeMySQLDump.sql"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly that was my initial thought that might be the best way, I just hadn't tested it out. phpMyAdmin isn't an option as the user won't have access and this needs to be done automatically via an auto web install interface.